# React-router-dom Link does not update history in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom

Example code:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { MemoryRouter, Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

type TRoutes = {
  [key: string]: {
    title?: string;
    path: string;
    component: FC;
  };
};

const routes: TRoutes = {
  start: {
    title: 'start page',
    path: `/`,
    component: () => null
  },
  destination: {
    path: `/destination`,
    component: () => null
  }
};

const initialEntries = [routes.start.path];

const history = createMemoryHistory({
  initialEntries
});

let wrapper: ReactWrapper;

describe('Router test', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={initialEntries}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Link to={routes.destination.path}>Go to destination</Link>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              history.push(routes.destination.path);
            }}
          >
            Go to route
          </button>
          <Switch>
            <Route path={routes.start.path} exact component={routes.start.component} />
            <Route path={routes.destination.path} exact component={routes.destination.component} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  });
  describe('Link', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      history.push(routes.start.path);
    });
    it(`should render Link - Go to destination`, () => {
      expect(wrapper.find('a').at(0).exists).toBeTruthy();
    });
    it(`should update history from='${routes.start.path}' to location='${routes.destination.path}' on Link click`, () => {
      wrapper
        .find('a')
        .at(0)
        .simulate('click');
      // wrapper.update();
      expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual(routes.destination.path);
    });
  });
  describe('button', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      history.push(routes.start.path);
    });
    it(`should render button - Go to destination`, () => {
      expect(wrapper.find('button').at(0).exists).toBeTruthy();
    });
    it(`should update history from='${routes.start.path}' to location='${routes.destination.path}' on history.push`, () => {
      wrapper
        .find('button')
        .at(0)
        .simulate('click');
      // wrapper.update();
      expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual(routes.destination.path);
    });
  });
});
```

I have 4 tests above.

- it should test that the link exists = pass
- on click of link it should update the history = fail
- it should test that the button exists = pass
- on click of button it should update the history = pass

The history updates only when I do history.push, but not when clicking the Link.

From the documents on - react-router-dom, it implies that this approach is valid and should work:
https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing

```js
 the url bar), you can add a route that updates a variable in the test:// app.test.js
test("clicking filter links updates product query params", () => {
  let history, location;
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/my/initial/route"]}>
      <App />
      <Route
        path="*"
        render={({ history, location }) => {
          history = history;
          location = location;
          return null;
        }}
      />
    </MemoryRouter>,
    node
  );

  act(() => {
    // example: click a <Link> to /products?id=1234
  });

  // assert about url
  expect(location.pathname).toBe("/products");
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  expect(searchParams.has("id")).toBe(true);
  expect(searchParams.get("id")).toEqual("1234");
});
```

Any advice on this?

thanks

Comment: try to debug by your own by setting breakpoint in [`node_modules/react-router-dom/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js). At least you will see if handler is called. Also don't nest `Router` into `MemoryRouter` they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @skyboyer thanks for suggestion. MemoryRouter doesn't have a property history, so didn't think this would automatically pick up the history I have created via createMemoryHistory. In anycase, removing Router did not solve this problem.